# Present simple or Present perfect?

Tags: verb-usage

Which tense to choose: "Is dinner ready? - I'm afraid, it isn't. The potatoes ***are not done/haven't been done*** yet."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To say the potatoes are not finished cooking

> The potatoes are not done *yet*.
>   *the potatoes are not finished cooking*

If you say

> The potatoes haven't been done.
>   *the potatoes have not been prepared yet*

that would mean no preparation has been made for the potatoes e.g. they have not been boiled to make mashed potatoes, in the second sentence "done" = "prepared".

Comment: Thank you very much. So, according to your answer, the second sentence isn't correct, is it?

Comment: The second sentence is grammatically correct, it's just that it has a different meaning.  Eventhough "The potatoes are not *prepared* yet" can be used in both circumstances "have not been done" implies there are several steps to prepare the potatoes.

Comment: I have changed this question. Could you tell me if both answers are still OK now, please?

Comment: The meaning of your question has not changed, and so the meaning of the answers have not changed either.